# Find all homomorphisms from $S_3$ to $C_6$. Are there any isomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find all homomorphisms from $S_3$ to $C_6$. Are there any isomorphisms? Recall that
>   \begin{align}
> S_3 = \langle x,y : x^2 = y^2 = (xy)^3 = (yx)^3 = e \rangle.
> \end{align}

Suppose the cyclic group $C_6$ is generated by an element $z$, so we can say $C_6 = \langle z \rangle$. Now suppose $f$ is a homomorphism from $S_3$ to $C_6$. Then (according to my teacher), $f(x), f(y) \in \{e,z^3\}$. How is this so? If I understand this, I think I would be able to complete this proof on my own.

---

**Hint** for why $\{f(x),f(y)\}=\{e,z^3\}$.  Evaluate $f(x^2)$ in two ways, one using the definition of "homomorphism" and another using the definition of $S_3$.

Assuming $f(x)$ is a homomorphism, then if $f(x) = e$, $f(x^2) = f(x)^2 = e^2 = e$. If $f(x) = z^3$, then  $f(x)^2 = (z^3)^2 = (z^6) = e$. If $f(x)$ is anything else, then we won't get $f(x^2) = e$. Therefore $f(x) \in \{e,z^3\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** for why $f(x),f(y)\in\{e,z^3\}$.  Evaluate $f(x^2)$ in two ways, one using the definition of "homomorphism" and another using the definition of $S_3$.

**Hint** for "are there any isomorphisms?" - do you know any important fact about $C_6$ which is not true for $S_3$?

Comment: Working on it. The two groups are of the same order, so based on that an isomoprhism may exist. I know that if $f(x) \not= f(y)$, then there may be an isomorphism. On the other hand, if $f(x) = f(y)$, then injectiviy fails, so no isomorphism can exist.

Comment: Sure, but there is a very easy short cut.  I guess it depends on how much you have studied these two groups so far.

Comment: Well, I do know that $S_3 = \{e,(12),(13),(23),(123),(132)\}$ and $C_6 = \{e,z,z^2,z^3,z^4,z^5\}$ (if $C_6$ were to be generated by $z$, of course).

Comment: it is clear that one is not abelian and the other is

Comment: @David Hmm I'm kind of stuck still on the hint (see my attempt in edited question).

Comment: So, $f(x)^2=e$ in $C_6$.  Which of the elements in $C_6$ have square equal to $e$?

Comment: $e$ and $z^3$ only?

Comment: Yes.  So this should explain your teacher's hint.  See if you can finish the question from here, see also comment by @janmarqz.

Comment: If $f(x) \not= f(y)$, then either $f(x)=e,f(y)=z^3$ or vice versa. Either case, we have $[f(x)f(y)]^3 = (z^3)^3 = z^3 \not= e$. So that's a contradiction; $f$ is not a homomorphism after all. Right? Also, as per @janmarqz's comment, since $S_3$ is symmetric and $C_6$ is cyclic, and isomorphisms preserve structure, we must have no isomorphisms here.

Comment: Looks good to me!  Well done.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C_6$ be generated by an element $z$; that is $C_6 = \langle z \rangle$. Let $f$ also be a homomorphism from $S_3$ to $C_6$. Then it is true that $$f(x),f(y) \in \{e,z^3\}$$

If $f(x) \not= f(y)$, then $$(f(x)f(y))^3=(z^3)^3 = z^3 \not= e$$
So $f$ is not a homomorphism in this case. Therefore we must have $f(x)=f(y)$.

If $f(x) =e= f(y)$, then $$(f(x)f(y))^3=(e \cdot e)^3 = e$$
So $f$ is a homomorphism if it sends all elements of $x,y$ to $e$.

If $f(x) = z^3 = f(y)$, then $$(f(x)f(y)^3=(z^3 \cdot z^3)^3 = (z^6)^3 = e^3 = e$$
So $f$ is also a homomorphism if it sends all elements of $x,y$ to $z^3$.